# Swift: Adding floating button to TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having trouble at TableViewController.
I want to add floating button, but I found out that if I create tableview with TableviewController in Storyboard, then tableview is superview in that view controller, which means only way to add button is adding button in tableview as one of a cell, which is not floating button. (Maybe I'm wrong. I'm a bit confused. I can't add another view by Storyboard.)
I googled several times and I think the only solution is to add button by using UIWindow, but part of the solution codes are deprecated.
I hope I can get alternate solution for my problem.

Comment: Instead of using UITableViewController, use UIViewController and add UITableView and button in UIViewController class.

Comment: @jpatrick I Added answer below, if you find the answer helpful and solving your problem, you can accept it likewise: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. i guess i'd better not use uitableviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the best solution is using `UIViewController` and adding `UITableView` and your button as subviews (as @Surjeet Singh suggested in comment). However if you face troubles doing this (maybe too complex right now), you can add `UIButton` as subview of your `keyWindow` as workaround. however keep in mind that you need to manually remove the `button` from `keyWindow` once your `UITableViewController` is going to disappear, or else your button will be appearing on other `UIViewControllers`. Here is the workaround solution:

```
    func addFloatingButton() {
    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    keyWindow?.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: I guess I will go for fixing my code from uitableviewcontroller to uiviewcontroller. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure! It is propably the best you can do. Anyway, try to close the question once it is not valid anymore, so it will not appear in opened questions. You can do it either by writing answer to your own question and accepting it, or accepting some of the existing answers. Closing question helps SO community to focus on current and actual questions.